# Changing Dropdown values Through iMacro

Tags: javascript, imacros, sap-web-ide

I am just a newbie, I am working on a SAP webserver made with lots of Javascript which is going off the top of my head.

There are few dropdown boxes where i have to select one by one but same values again and again. to save my time i decided to record through iMacro. it is recording and changing within a second but problem is Dropdown values sets to default after a second it changed by iMacro.

Other Things i have done already i am just stuck here.

iMacro Script

```
FRAME F=8
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:sap.client.SsrClient.form ATTR=ID:WD0208 
CONTENT=MEDIUM
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:sap.client.SsrClient.form ATTR=ID:WD0216 
CONTENT=F.O.R
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:sap.client.SsrClient.form ATTR=ID:WD0220 
CONTENT=Unloading<SP>By<SP>Customer<SP>And<SP>Octroi<SP>By<SP>Company
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:sap.client.SsrClient.form ATTR=ID:WD023B 
CONTENT=PPC-ULTRATECH<SP>CEMENT-HDPE<SP>/<SP>PP<SP>PACK<SP>(MRP)
```

Kindly help

Comment: Mention your FCI (Full Config Info) for me to have a look if you don't get any Replies (I don't answer otherwise), hum and no URL posted, you might want to open a parallel Thread on the (iOpus/Ipswitch) iMacros Forum where I might be able to help you a bit more precisely... (Mod there...) (And we can always post the/a Final Solution here afterwards...) Correct Spelling is 'iMacros' btw...!! (x4...!)

Comment: Dear Sir, Thread Submitted to iMacros Forum, Kindly Check

Comment: For those "interested", parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum:  
https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29901  
(I'll post "later" the Solution here once @OP's Script will be working...)